# My CSS is overwritten by the style agent

Tags: css

Although the .CSS works for all of the elements I have added it won't work for the 'Subscribe Now' button.

Here's the CSS

```
subbutton
{
    background-image:url(images/button_gradient.png); border:2px solid #FFFFFF !important;
    background-color:#be0000;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
    color: #F8F8F8;
    border-color: #be0000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    line-height: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

and here's the HTML

```
<div class="af-element buttonContainer">
   <input name="Subscribe" class="subbutton" type="submit" value="Subscribe Now!" tabindex="503" />
   <div class="af-clear">
   </div>
</div>
```

It looks like my code it's overwritten by the default style agent stylesheet and I don't understand why.

Here's a link for the website: http://xn--mxadnimgroqkg.gr/fitnessforum/

Comment: In the CSS at the link you provided, you are using an id `#subbutton` and not a class `.subbutton`

Comment: I guess my mind stopped working! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use "." instead of "#" because you have to select the class not the id like this:

```
.subbutton

    {
        background-image:url(images/button_gradient.png); border:2px solid #FFFFFF !important;
        background-color:#be0000;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
        color: #F8F8F8;
        border-color: #be0000;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        line-height: 15px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS rule is using an **id** selector `#subbutton` and your markup is using the **class** selector `.subbutton`. Making the selector rule and the use of it consistent (i.e. either use `#` or `.` in both places) will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

can it be that simple as a typo in your CSS?

```
.subbutton
{
  /* your css */
}
```

Notice the . (dot) before you selector

Answer (score 0):

You have used **id** selector in css file: #subbutton, but you specified **class** attribute in the HTML code :  class="subbutton"

Answer (score 0):

The CSS should be...

```
.subbutton
{
...
}
```

To match the input...

```
<input name="Subscribe" class="subbutton" type="submit" value="Subscribe Now!" tabindex="503" />
```

You are currently using an id...

```
#subbutton
{
...
}
```